# Converting months to another language

Tags: php, date

I have a date returned from by Database (oracle) in a format like this 01-MAY-11 :
and to convert the month from english to frensh (MAY to Mai) ,
I did this :

```
        $date=str_replace("JAN","Janvier",$date);
        $date=str_replace("FEB","Février",$date);
        $date=str_replace("MAR","Mars",$date);
        $date=str_replace("APR","Avril",$date);
        $date=str_replace("MAY","Mai",$date);
        $date=str_replace("JUN","Juin",$date);
        $date=str_replace("JUL","Juillet",$date);
        $date=str_replace("AUG","Août",$date);
        $date=str_replace("SEPT","Septembre",$date);
        $date=str_replace("OCT","Octobre",$date);
        $date=str_replace("NOV","Novembre",$date);
        $date=str_replace("DEC","Décembre",$date);
```

But i find it ugly so is there a more concise way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: The locale-based answers below are the best way to go for your PHP logic, but you might consider extracting from the database using the [`TO_CHAR`](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html#date%20format) function, e.g. `SELECT TO_CHAR(datefield, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` to avoid any strtotime problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use array for storing translation of months:

```
$mc = array("jan"=>"Janvier","feb"=>"Février", ....); //(and so on)

$new_date = explode('-',$date);
$new_date[1] = $mc[strtolower($new_date[1])];
$new_date = implode('-',$new_date);
```

of course, you need to check if its date and make sure month is always second

Comment: this method isn't really cleaner (or a little bit) than the way proposed by the op. But it may be useful to know that in fact this method has the advantage to be independent from locals install on the server system

Comment: I prefer this one. If I want another language, or diffrent translation than standard, then the only thing i need to change is key and values in array. It's more reusable, and that is what i have in mind when i think "less ugly" ;o)

Comment: I didnt want to change my local setting so i prefer this solution , thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

use this

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'fr_FR');

echo strftime("%d %b %Y", strtotime($date)); //use your dates timestamp
?>
```

Comment: The only thing to bear in mind with this solution is the ambiguity of the year portion of Oracle's output; Using `TO_CHAR` as above will remove this.

Comment: using 'DD-Mon-YYYY' format in oracle query will resolve ambiguity

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your locals settings using setlocale for getting date months and days in the desired languages

here's a basic exemple:

```
// here's a current list of locales you can find on systems for french 
$locales = array('fr_FR.utf8','fr_FR.UTF8','fr_FR.utf-8','fr_FR.UTF-8','fr_FR','fr');
setlocale(LC_TIME,$locales);
//now you can call your localized date function
```

If you don't want to change the locale setting for the rest of the application you can keep trace of currently setted locale and restore it after your date call like this:

```
// keep track of locals setting:
$loc = setlocale(LC_TIME,0);
$tmpLoc = setlocale(LC_TIME,$locales);
//your date call here and then restore locale setting
setlocale(LC_TIME,$loc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although the locale solutions are best, it is also possible to `TO_CHAR` with the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` option to output this directly from Oracle:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD-MONTH-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=French') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

OO Style:

```
<?php
class FrDate extends DateTime 
{
    public function month($format) 
    {
        $english = array('Jan','Febr','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec');
        $french = array('Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre');

        return str_replace($english, $french, parent::format($format));
    }
}

$date = new FrDate('26 Dec 2011');

echo $date->month('M'); //Output: Décembre
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set up a lookup array which relates the two languages, just use `strtr()` to apply the **str**ing **tr**anslation.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/6G1Vg))

```
$enToFr = [
    "JAN" => "Janvier",
    "FEB" => "Février",
    "MAR" => "Mars",
    "APR" => "Avril",
    "MAY" => "Mai",
    "JUN" => "Juin",
    "JUL" => "Juillet",
    "AUG" => "Août",
    "SEPT" => "Septembre",
    "OCT" => "Octobre",
    "NOV" => "Novembre",
    "DEC" => "Décembre"
];

$date = '01-MAY-11';

echo strtr($date, $enToFr);
// 01-Mai-11
```

If you know that you'll need to use this in multiple places in your project, you might declare it as a constant (since it won't logically change) to enjoy global scope/access.

Since it is a single native function, I don't really advise making a wrapper/helper function to perform the same process by a different function name.